# PHP : authentication with a temporary link

Tags: php, authentication

in my system users register with their email address and receive a temporary link to log in.

```
hostname/login/OYkwIJt6be1V5kMg10G
```

1. The token must be generated from the email adress of user and valid for 2 hours.
2. I don't want to store a session or token in a given database

In my mind I imagine creating the link like this:

```
$token = md5(((email + time() + SALT))
$link = $host.$path.$token
```

Is this a good way to process? What would be the cleanest, simplest and easiest method to manage?

The USER table schematic looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
    `ip_adress` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `created` date NOT NULL,
    `last_login` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

thank you for your recommendations

**Edit**

I opted for [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55516344/785515) according to your recommendations.

> the best solution I found is using OpenSSL. It is built into PHP and
>   you don't need any external library.

sample:

```
function encrypt($key, $payload) {
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
  $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($payload, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, 0, $iv);
  return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
}

function decrypt($key, $garble) {
    list($encrypted_data, $iv) = explode('::', base64_decode($garble), 2);
    return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, 0, $iv);
}

$email = "firstname.lastname@domain.com";
$expire = time()+7200;
$data = $email.'-'.$expire;

$secret = 'h6k8TG2x03';

/* encrypt */
$token = encrypt($secret, $data);

/* user auth */
http://domain.com/?token=YSBzbGlnaHRseSBsb25nZXIgdGVzdCBmb3IgdGV2ZXIK==

/* decrypt */
$decrypted = decrypt($secret, $_GET['token']);
```

Comment: One issue I see here is that you appear to be using a hard-coded secret.  This is not a good practice for security.  Are you inserting a record in the users table at the time you create this link or at the time of confirmation?

Comment: @JimmyJames no. But I think understand the idea behind your question.

Comment: I take no to mean after confirmation?

Comment: @JimmyJames I have more confidence in concealing SALT hard in the code instead in the database. Maybe I'm wrong in my raisonnnement?

Comment: So a salt and a secret are two different things.  Salts do not need to be secret but as Sean Burton notes, should not be shared between users.  Your secret is the key to the encrypted data.  The problem with hardcoding it is that it will tend to become not a secret.  At the very least, I would recommend generating a new random secret (key) every hour and checking against the current and prior secrets.  Do you have a place you can store and retrieve two secrets?

Comment: @Sandra the word salt is a little misleading. Salt has a specific meaning, which doesn't apply to what you're doing. It's better to call what you have simply a secret.

Answer (score 3):

If the token is not stored in the system then the system must be able to read the information (i.e. email, created time) from the token itself. That means you have to do encryption instead of one way hash.

How to do the encryption is already explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262109/simplest-two-way-encryption-using-php)

Comment: The OP needs to authenticate the information, not encrypt it.

Comment: Symmetric encryption is perfectly valid solution for generating temporary login link and validating it.

Answer (score 2):

You want to generate a message on the server, send it by email, then have someone recieve the email and give the message back to you. You'll check that the message is authentic before letting them log in.

So you're looking for a [Message Authentication Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) (MAC). This requires you to have a secret you keep on the server and follow a MAC algorithm that has been described and found to be hard to break by multiple cryptography researchers to generate and check an authenticated message.

In general with anything cryptography related you should look for techniques that are well known in the literature and considered appropriate for your particular use case, rather than trying to invent anything of your own, unless you are in the business of cryptography research. (And even if you are in that business, probably don't use your own techniques until after publishing them as research and having other people study them for years and reccomend them)

One implementation of MAC you might want to consider is the PHP built in function [hash_hmac](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php).

Answer (score 1):

The way you have capitalised the `SALT` and don't seem to be including it in the link seems to suggest that you would be using the same salt for every hash? If so, this defeats the purpose of using a salt.

If you're going to use a hash with a salt then you *must* generate a new salt for each hash, then include the salt in the token you return so it can be verified. Otherwise the token values will be predictable and could potentially be guessed by an attacker.

Of course, using encryption to encrypt the token as suggested in the other answers is another good way of making the tokens unpredictable.

Comment: What the OP is calling SALT is really functioning as a secret, not a salt, and it needs to stay secret. If it was included in plaintext with the token then an attacker could make up their own secret and make a forged token with it.

Comment: That makes sense, in that case it's being used more like a [pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography)) than a salt.